# actionbar's upNavigation from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have to jump from activity A to fragment2 in activity B(in the activityB, i use the viewpager,which contains four fragment).what i want is when i use the upNavigation of the actionbar ,i just jump to the exact second fragment.

can anyone help me?(i have searched for some related questions ,but it seems they all navigate in/between the fragments,which is not my want.)

Comment: do u navigate to Activity A from Activity B ?

Comment: yes, i want to reach the fragment2 in activityB@AsifMujteba

Answer (score 0):

Use this , detect the onclick

```
ViewPager.setCurrentItem(pageNumber);
```

above line will navigate you to that page